# Vb.net windows form, cannot open another main form when it is already open

Tags: vb.net, winforms

In this case, after I click the button from the second form, it open the another mainform even it already exists. what should i do?

//MainForm form

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_meron.Click
    Dim vartxt = "Meron"
    Dim frm_docpopup As New frm_Docs_PopUp(vartxt)
    frm_docpopup.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

//Second Form

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim vartxt = Label5.Text
    Dim totalAmount = Label3.Text
    Dim frm_mainform As New MainForm(vartxt, totalAmount)
    frm_mainform.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

Comment: Of course it creates a new mainform. What do you think `New MainForm()` does? Did you try removing that line and the `frm_mainform.Show()` and just hiding your second form? What happens then?

Comment: You might find it worth while reading up on showdialog and modal forms.  If done properly, you likely find you don’t need to handle the button click events in the frm_docs_popup

Comment: Why do this? A ShowDialog'd form appears in front of the form that ShowDialog'd it, and the form behind becomes non-interactive while the dialog is open. There's no point hiding it